# iOS Keyboard with Textarea using PhoneGap

Tags: ios, cordova

I'm not sure what to call it, but I'd like to do this with the iOS keyboard using PhoneGap:

http://cdn.iphoneincanada.ca/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/bold-dark-keyboard-ios-7.1-beta.png

Basically, you can type in a little thing right above the keyboard just like in Messages or Facebook App.

Comment: You need keyboard when app opened ? Or when tapped on text input  box?

Comment: I want the keyboard to open with a text area attached to the keyboard.